# SAS joining table and creating multiple columns based on data from other columns individually

Tags: join, sas

Good Morning,

Sorry I am completely self taught so am probably missing something simple, I am trying to create a table based on values from other tables. I am not sure how to best explain what I want so here is the example;

Table1

```
Name   Lname   Issue1 Issue2  Issue3
Tom    Smith   1234   1258    1175
Dick   Scott   1258   1158    1852
Jane   Davis   1234   1385    1111
Sarah  Bennet  1158   1672    1234
```

Table2

```
Issue  Desc
1234   A
1258   B
1175   C
1158   D
1852   E
1385   F
1111   G
1672   H
1468   I
```

Want

```
Name   Lname   Issue1 Desc1 Issue2 Desc2  Issue3  Desc3
Tom    Smith   1234   A     1258   B      1175    C
Dick   Scott   1258   B     1158   D      1852    E
Jane   Davis   1234   A     1385   F      1111    G
Sarah  Bennet  1158   D     1672   H      1234    A
```

I have done this previously by doing multiple joins to a single table but it seems like there should be a better way, here is what I am currently using

```
Proc SQL;
Select
a.Name
a.Lname
a.Issue1
b.Desc as Desc1 
a.Issue2
c.Desc as Desc2 
a.Issue3
d.Desc as Desc3 

From work.Table1 a

Left Join work.Table2 b
on a.Issue1 eq b.Desc

Left Join work.Table2 c
on a.Issue2 eq c.Desc

Left Join work.Table2 d
on a.Issue3 eq d.Desc
```

So basically I want a table that has data from both but need multiple descriptions from Table 2 to match the issue values from table 1.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should transpose your data from wide to long, as e. g. in this [example](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n01rzqgzs8vq1bn10h1wtx914kyf.htm) using `PROC TRANSPOSE`. It is often better to have data in the "long" format, e. g. to use `BY`-grouping in statistical procedures.

First sort the `BY`-variables.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by Name Lname;
run;
```

Then transpose all variables `Issue1-3`.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want;
  by Name Lname;
  var Issue:;
run;
```

Then join with `Table2`.

Comment: Thank you! I attempted this with my data set but the transpose did not work (not enough memory), the base data set I am working with has 80 Issue columns and 429k rows.

Comment: Are you sure it was memory and not disk space?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a format from Table 2
2. Use an Array in a data step to create the new columns in Table 1 if required, or apply format.

```
data issue_fmt;
set table2;
start=issue;
label=desc;
fmtname='$Issue_fmt';
type='C';
run;

proc format cntlin=issue_fmt;
run;

*apply format;
proc print data=table1 (obs=10);
var issue1-issue3;
format issue1-issue3 $issue_fmt.;
run;

*create new variable with format;

data want;
set have;

array issues(*) issue1-issue200;
array desc(200) desc1-desc200;

do i=1 to dim(issues);
  desc(i) = put(issues(i), $issue_fmt.);
end;

run;
```